# Which Azure VM would I need to allow me to run python scripts and push data to azure sql database

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm looking to use get an azure VM so that I can schedule a python script to run overnight.  The data from the script will be getting pushed to my sql database.

I'm looking at the VM configurations and not sure which one to go with, although it would need to the windows.

Am I correct in thinking that a simple Windows OS VM would work?   ....and then within the VM I just install python and SSMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to run your Python code on a schedule.  I'd suggest you take a look at Azure Functions as they can run on a schedule and cost you much less to run as you only pay for the executions compared to a VM that runs 24/7.